# Parent group isn't counting contact in child groups

Tags: groups

In the WordPress demo site I just create a group called `parent_01` and a child group inside this one called `child_01`.
I create a contact called `test1` and added to `child_01` gruop, but in the `Manage Groups` screen the parent group has `0` in the `count` field
Is this a correct behaviour?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This is a limitation of current implementation, "Parent Group" contact count does not include "Child Group" contact count. So I would call this a missing feature :)

Answer (score 2):

Since clicking 'Contacts' on the parent group does show the contact you added, this looks like a bug. I tested the same setup on dmaster.demo.civicrm.org and see the same behavior, so it doesn't appear to be 4.6 specific. I ran the job to rebuild the smart group cache as well, with no change.

Please file a bug when you get a chance.

Comment: If I click on `Contact` on the parent group, the contacts are well displayed (at least with one contact test). Anyway I will file the bug because from your words I assume that this behaviour, label `Count`0, isn't the correct one

Comment: Exactly. The behavior itself is working, but the counter field is not.

Comment: Pls paste bug link back here if you did add it to JIRA

Comment: Yes please, posting a link to your bugreport would help greatly!  Thanks

Comment: Here's the issue in Jira: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-17455?jql=text%20~%20%22parent%20counting%20child%20groups%22